# Python - Loading files relative from project root

Tags: python, oop

My project layout is as follows:

```
├ ...
├── pve
│   ├── blahblah
│   │   ├── TestDefinition.py
│   │   ├── TestDefinition.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   └── pve.py
├── src
│   └── definitions
│       └── THISFILE.yml
└── ...
```

I need to be able to fetch files (THISFILE.yml for example) from src/definitions by the pve/blahblah/TestDefinition.py class.

How do I properly access the project root? Once I have that, I can access the .yml files relative.
TIA.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I like to create some sort of configuration file in the project root that has an aboslute path to the root. I do this only because the frameworks i usually use (django, scrapy) have some sort of convention like this

```
├ ...
├── pve
│   ├── blahblah
│   │   ├── TestDefinition.py
│   │   ├── TestDefinition.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   └── pve.py
├── src
│   └── definitions
│       └── THISFILE.yml
└── settings.py



# settings.py

import os
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DEFINITIONS_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'src', 'definitions')


from myproject import settings 
settings.DEFINITIONS_ROOT
```

Comment: Cool - good idea. I'm a .py noob so I'm learning and trying not to take too many conventions from other languages in order to learn the 'python way'. heh.

Comment: @dm03514 Are you referring to `myproject` here as the project root folder that contains 'pve' and 'src' folders. I am trying something similar, but importing a file from root directory requires placing `__init__` file at the project root. Is it advisable ? Thanks.